# How do I issue SELECT queries on both tables in an M:N relationship?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a SQLite database with table `authors` (columns `id`, `name`), table `books` (columns `id`, `title`), and table `books_authors_link` (columns `id`, `book_id`, `author_id`).

Ideally, I would like to issue a query where each row of the result has `book.title` and `author.name`, so that iterating over the result I could easily print `"I, Partridge" by Alan Partridge`.

So what am I trying to select here? `SELECT name FROM authors AND title FROM books WHERE books.id = authors.id` or something... I can't quite work it out and would appreciate a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.title, a.name
  from authors a
  join books_authors_link bal
    on a.id = bal.author_id
  join books b
    on b.id = bal.book_id
```

You just need to join the tables based on the relationships you implied between the tables.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this. Works perfectly and gives me a good starting point for learning about joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Inner Join`

```
Select A.name,B.title from TB_authors A inner join TB_books B on A.id = B.id where B.id = 'xxx'
```